# Limit of sums of iid random variables which are not square-integrable

Tags: probability-theory

The Central Limit Theorem tells us that for an iid sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ of finite variance $\sigma^2$ and zero mean

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}=^d N(0,\sigma^2)$$

where $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$.

Suppose we have a similar sequence, except now we suppose that $X_n$ has infinite variance. Then is it possible for the sequence $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ to converge in distribution? Is there always some $\alpha$ such that $n^\alpha S_n$ converges to a non-constant distribution?

(It seems to me that the answer to the first question should be no, but I'm having trouble showing this.)

Thank you.

Comment: There is the Cauchy distribution for instance. But there are many other distributions with infinite variance. You'll need to specify more to have a definite limiting distribution.

Comment: Suppose the random variables have symmetric density $f(x)$ and $f(x)$ is asymptotic to $|x|^{-(1+\alpha)}$ as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$.  If $\alpha >2$, then the central limit theorem applies.  If $0 < \alpha <2$, then $\frac{S_n}{n^{1/\alpha}}$ converges in distribution to a symmetric $\alpha$-stable distribution.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The generalized central limit theorem states (see [this](http://wolfram.com/xid/0bnhgp071je6i-n2cz0t) for a summary), that if $X_i$ are i.i.d. such that its density function has left tail power-law asymptotic $\mathbb{P}(X < -x) \sim d x^{-\mu}$ and right tail asymptotic $\mathbb{P}(X > x) \sim 1- c x^{-\mu}$ as $x \to +\infty$, then there exist sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that the random variate $Z_n = ((\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) - a_n )/b_n$ converges in probability to a stable distribution with stability index $\alpha = \min(\mu, 2)$ and asymmetry parameter $\beta = \frac{c-d}{c+d}$.

Details on the constructive choice of sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ are given in the table found at the link above. Also see [page 62](http://books.google.com/books?id=ExN8DXXrNE8C&lpg=PR21&ots=OwMgedxSPt&dq=Zolotarev%20Uchaikin&pg=PA62#v=onepage&q=centering%20and%20normalizing&f=false) of Zolotarev and Uchaikin on Google books.